# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I keep getting this error : `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute`

```
protected void SendAddedMessages(IEnumerable<int> receiverIds, Result result)
{
    foreach (var receiverId in receiverIds)
    {
        SendAddMessage(receiverId, result);
    }
}
```

I understand what it means but the problem is that as you can see i'm not modifying it anywhere, the call to my function is `SendAddedMessages(result.People.Select(r => r.Id), result);`

I think i can just cast it as an array and just use a for loop but what i want to know it where/why is it modified. This is an MVC application and i'm using EntityFramework, could there be another thread doing this ?

**Update 1 added the SendAddMessage**

```
protected void SendAddMessage(int recevierId, Result result)
{
    Messaging.SendMessage(
            recevierId,
            "Some text",
            String.Format(CommonString.AddedToResult, result.Name, Name)
        );
}
```

Comment: What does SendAddMessage do?

Comment: @Bogdan I've added the function, but does it make any difference ?, i send an int as a parameter so it gets passed by value, it's not like i can delete it. Anyway i don't access the collection anywhere else from this function call. That's why it bothers me so much

Comment: I think People belongs to a DbContext, so you iterate on this context, and something you do should modify the context. Using People.Select(...)**.ToList()** will take the IEnumerable out of the context.

Comment: "I keep getting"... like, always? Or sometimes? When it's sometimes it's bound to be related to threading. What's the lifespan of `result`? (I assume it's a context?)

Comment: @tschmit007 i kind of got that, but what's not clear to me is why does this happen, my controllers implement IDisposable, and i create a new DbContext at every request i'm not explicitly using TPL or something else for threading

Comment: @GertArnold i only get it sometimes i explained it in the comment above

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the content of the database table changes during the (probable relatively lengthy) process of sending mails. The db reader is reading while the collection is enumerated and prior to EF6 this read is not from a snapshot by default. That's why it's always good practice to take control over when a query is actually executed and to execute it quickly.

Comment: @GertArnold can you post this as an answer and provide a link to some documentation about what you said about the snapshot before EF6 so i can mark it as correct

Comment: Sure, I'll do that. But is this likely at all? Any chance that the table is actually modified during the process?

Comment: @toby This is a nice puzzle you have here. My guess is that somewhere you update a object that is stored in the People DbSet. The DbSet will then notice the change and will invalidate the enumerator used by the Select. Since linq uses lazy evaluation it will fail.

Comment: @GertArnold the database yes the content of the collection should though, in my send function i'm adding creating a message with that person as the receiver and saving it, that's my only guess but i still think this shouldn't happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that the content of the database table changes during the (probable relatively lengthy) process of sending mails. The db reader is reading while the collection is enumerated and prior to EF6 this read is not from a snapshot by default. See [Entity Framework 6: The Ninja Edition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/magazine/dn532202%28en-us%29.aspx), look for `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.

That's why it's always good practice to take control over when a query is actually executed and to execute it quickly. Personally, I'd prefer an argument like `ICollection<int> receiverIds`, so I know that I receive an enumerated collection, not a lazy loading bomb.

**EDIT**
After your final comment, saving objects that are related to `People` may cause collections to modify deeper in EF's machinery, because EF will also run `DetectChanges`, which may touch existing associations.